# Agora Web SDK Screen share not returning video track

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have integrated Screen Share function on my web conference and Screen Share content will show on users who are in the session before Screen Share start, but it does not work on user who have joined the session after the Screen Share have started.
Below is the logic for getting video tracks when new user join the session.

```
// Add current users
        this.meetingSession.remoteUsers.forEach(async ru => {
          if (ru.uid.search('screen_') > -1) {
            this.getScreenShare(ru);
            return;
          }

          let remoteVideo = await this.meetingSession.subscribe(ru, 'video');
          this.setVideoAudioElement(ru, 'video');
          let remoteAudio = await this.meetingSession.subscribe(ru, 'audio');
          this.setVideoAudioElement(ru, 'audio');
        })

async getScreenShare (user) {
     ...
      this.currentScreenTrack = user.videoTrack;

// Here user.videoTrack is undefined
console.log(user)

      ...
    },
```

After the new user's session is created, I'm getting the current user's video track from "remoteUsers" object inside session object. No problem with regular user's video track, but Screen Share object say "hasVideo" is true but "videoTrack" is undefined.

[Agora Web SDK meetingSession.remoteUsers Screen Share Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc44K.png)

Is this a specification that videoTrack is not included in meetingSession.remoteUsers for Screen Share?

I'm wondering what method people are using to show Screen Share content for user who have joined the session during Screen Share.

It will be great if someone can give me suggestion about this.

"agora-rtc-sdk-ng": "^4.6.2",

Answer (score 0):

I had it figured out.
I just needed to subscribe the remote user.

```
this.meetingSession.remoteUsers.forEach(async ru => {
      if (ru.uid.search('screen_') > -1) {

        // Just needed to subscribe the user...
        await this.meetingSession.subscribe(ru, 'video');
        
        this.getScreenShare(ru);
        return;
      }

      let remoteVideo = await this.meetingSession.subscribe(ru, 'video');
      this.setVideoAudioElement(ru, 'video');
      let remoteAudio = await this.meetingSession.subscribe(ru, 'audio');
      this.setVideoAudioElement(ru, 'audio');
    })
```